# Firebug duplicate 404 errors

Tags: firebug

Just wondering why firebug always duplicated 404 messages?

I only call the image once in my document, but I always get the message twice.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<body class='view content'>
    <div id="container">

        <h1>Test 7 Commercial &nbsp;/&nbsp; <span>commercial</span></h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sem nisi, mollis pellentesque fringilla eu, vulputate sit amet leo. Nullam vel augue id sapien facilisis vestibulum. Mauris molestie suscipit est id volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus orci sem, rutrum reas.<br />
<br />
ulputate sit amet leo. Nullam vel augue id sapien facilisis vestibulum. Mauris molestie suscipit est id volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus orci sem, rutrum qulputate sit amet leo. Nullam vel augue id sapien facilisis vestibulum. Mauris molestie suscipit est id volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus orci sem, rutrum.</p>


        <div class="heart">
            <img src="images/heart.pngs" class="hearty" /> 
            <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" id="facebook" class="sm_icon" alt="" /></a>  
            <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" id="twitter" class="sm_icon" alt="" /></a>    
            <a href="#"><img src="images/pinterest.png" id="pinterest" class="sm_icon" alt="" /></a>    
            <a href="#"><img src="images/google.png" id="google" class="sm_icon" alt="" /></a>  
        <!--heart--></div>
    <!--container--></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you manipulating with the image through javascript (moving around, removing and reinserting ...)?

Comment: @JanDvorak Let's cool it with the comments (this goes for RuralJuror as well).